# C language: there is a trailing character after the last character of my output

Tags: c, encryption, caesar-cipher

I am making a Caesar's Cipher for my lab sheet, and have made it able to encrypt 3 subtitution(Caesar's Cipher), which is the point of the exercise. But there has been one thing bugging me. First, there is a trailing character if i put it other than 3. For example, by typing "malware", and 2 for key.
This is my code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   char text[100];
   int key,i;

   printf("Please enter a word/sentence (lowercaps) for encrypting :\n ");
   fgets(text,100,stdin);
   printf("Please enter the key that you desire : eg:14\n");
   scanf("%d", &key);
   for(i=0;i<strlen(text);i++)
   {
      if (key>=26)
      {
         key=key%26;
      }
      if (text[i]==' ')
      {
         continue;
      }
      if(text[i]+key>'z')
      {
         text[i]-=97;
         text[i]+=26;
         text[i]+=key;
         text[i]%=26;
         text[i]+=97;
      }
      else
      {
         text[i]=text[i]+key;
      }
   }

   printf("this is your encrypted text : %s", text );
}
```

I hope I followed the correct indentation methods for coding. Got a lot of dislikes because of that

Comment: What do you mean exactly by trailing character ?
The trailing whitespaces ?

Comment: @Zermingore  Nope ,special characters .

Comment: yes, special characters from ASCII I assume. But I'm not sure why did it appear.

Comment: It's a new line character that gets converted by your ciphering I think.

Comment: I don't think this is right `if (key>=26)`, Shouldn't it be `if (key>26)` . At the end you'll need to nul terminate you string you created in text. Before the final `printf` add `text[i] = '\0';` and then you may wish to print your final string with a newline at the end so change `text : %s` to `text : %s\n`

Comment: Of course you don't even need the `if (key>26)`. You can just take the straight modulo without the `if` statement and just replace it with `key=key%26;`

Comment: You should fix-up `key` once, before you start the loop.  And you could use `key %= 26;` if you're sure the user entered a non-negative value.  If they might have entered a negative value, maybe you need `key = (key % 26 + 26) % 26;`.  Using `97` instead of `'97'` is not a particularly good idea.  Your code doesn't deal with upper-case letters or punctuation very well.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I think a check for negative number would be better up front since Caesar cypher is only valid for positive numbers (and in the case of 0 it doesn't encrypt).

Comment: To be clear (I forgot to mention this, my bad) I browsed the Internet and decided to just go with just small letters, that's why I did not use toUpper

Comment: Oops; my comment about _`97` instead of `'97'`_ should read **`97` instead of `'a'`**; my apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code is 1) not properly detecting when a `char` is a lower case letter  2) encrypting non-letters including `'\n'` from `fgets()` which is causing OP's "trailing character after the last character of my output".

Instead:

```
if (text[i] >= 'a' && text[i]<= 'z') {
   text[i] = (text[i] - 'a' + key)%26 + `a`;
}
else {
  ; // nothing 
}
```

Alternatively

```
if (islower((unsigned char) text[i]) {
   text[i] = (text[i] - 'a' + key)%26 + `a`;
}
```

Note: the above depends on `char` are encoded as [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).

A solution that does not depend on ASCII.

```
static const char lowercase[] = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
char *p = strchr(lowercase, text[i]);
if (p) {
  int offset = (p - lowercase + key)%26;
  text[i] = lowercase[offset];
}
```

Comment: how do I avoid the \n from getting into the buffer of fgets as well? Should I just go with your way?

Comment: For "a solution that does not depend on ASCII" you might as well use `toUpper`.

Comment: I have found quite an interesting solution to the trailing line, that is to use  strcpn [function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2693776/removing-trailing-newline-character-from-fgets-input) . This is the [link](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=strcspn&sektion=3) to the description of the function

Comment: @Hafiz Syazwan to "... avoid the \n from getting into the buffer of fgets as well" --> do _not_ avoid it.  Accept it. (BTW: it is not always there), _Then_ truncate it if exist.  `text[strcspn(text, "/n")]=0;` is a safe, easy method to do that.

Comment: @Jongware It is unclear how using `toUpper()`  (assume `toupper()`) would help.  OP is apparently not using upper case characters.

Comment: @chux: I got confused - apparently OP only wants lower case (which he calls "lowercaps", a nice portmanteau) encrypted. No need for stealth when SHOUTING, methinks.

Answer (score 0):

As Blake_Lead said, this '\0' character was changed in your cypher

Indeed I was wrong about the length of the buffer as fgets() puts a '\0'
From the manual page:

> A terminating null byte ('\0') is stored after the last character in the buffer.

So, you just need to change your test

```
if (text[i]==' ')
```

by something like:

```
 if (text[i] < 'A' || text[i] > 'z' || (text[i] > 'Z' && text[i] < 'a') )
```

Comment: So , `text` is a string other places should be `null` . This cant be reason for such behaviour .

Answer (score 0):

I will simplify and correct this code to

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char text[100];
    int key, i;
    printf("Enter a word / sentence (lowercaps) for encrypting : ");
    fgets(text, 100, stdin);
    printf("Enter the key that you desire (eg. 14) : ");
    scanf("%d", &key);
    key %= 26;    // Pull this out of the loop and remove the unnecessary if
    for (i = 0; text[i]; ++i) {    // Correct the loop condition
        if (text[i] == ' ') continue;
        if (text[i] + key > 'z')
            text[i] = (text[i] - 97 + 26) % 26 + 97;    // Simplify
        else
            text[i] += key;
    }
    printf("Encrypted text : %s\n", text);
    return 0;
}
```

**Input**

```
Enter a word / sentence (lowercaps) for encrypting : malware
Enter the key that you desire (eg. 14) : 2
```

**Output**

```
Encrypted text : ocnyctg
```

Comment: Actually you should check for value if `key=2` and its code for `y` remains `y` does not change   .

Comment: I keep looking at this code and thinking there is something wrong, you are encoding an extra character in `text` because of the newline returned by fgets

Comment: Where does the key get added when `text[i] + key > 'z'`?  Oops!  This would be more obvious with a bigger key, such as 21, than with a small one like 3.